# Punctuating lists containing negative elements

Tags: commas, negation, lists, semicolons

I came across some sentences similar to these:

- I would like my burger with no mustard, jalapeños, lettuce, and pickles.
- I would like my burger with mustard, no jalapeños, lettuce, and pickles.

I can't immediately tell whether the "no" is intended to apply to all of the elements in the list following "no" or only the element directly following it (although I do think the penultimate word would more naturally be "or" if "no" applied to all elements). I would find it less ambiguous when some elements have "no" but others don't.

- I would like my burger with: no mustard, jalapeños, no lettuce, and pickles.

I know the semicolon can be used as a ["super comma"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/531649/387877) for lists where elements contain commas, but I have not found anything about using it with negations such as above.

To reduce ambiguity, would it be acceptable to use semicolons as separators for lists such as this? Would it be preferred?

- I would like my burger with: no mustard; jalapeños; lettuce; pickles.

([This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/492065/how-do-i-punctuate-a-negated-list) is similar, but the answers don't address whether semicolons could or should be used.)

Comment: I would put the withs first and then list the withouts: "...burger with jalapenos, cheese, and pickles, but no lettuce, bacon, or mustard."

Comment: Add a colon after *with*. That's the simplest way of making it clear that the *no* applies only to a single list item. Or you can forego the colon and use numbers in parentheses before each list item. Or simply don't put a *no* item at the start of the list.

Comment: The essence of such sentences is that you group the list by type - first, all the positive/unqualified and then all the negative/qualified: *I would like my burger with  mustard, jalapeños, and lettuce, **but no/without** pickles, mayo, relish **or** eggs.*

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you are in front of a low-quality microphone-and-speaker at a fast food drive-through. If you want to be as clear as possible you'd say:

"I want my burger with mustard, lettuce, and pickles; but with no jalapenos, no onions, and no relish."

Comment: I am specifically dealing with written context in my situation. I do agree rewording it is the clearest option, written or spoken, but especially in spoken context.

Comment: Another way to make the items completely unambiguous would be something like <br/> "I want my burger with mustard, lettuce, and pickles; but without the following: jalapenos, onions, and relish. This also accomplishes the clear separation referenced by KannE, but seems  more awkward.